# Falacy in the arguement to show that $F$ is uniformly continuous in some punctured neighbourhood of $a$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, continuity, examples-counterexamples

> Given $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and $a\in \Bbb R$ define $F(x)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$ for $x\neq a$.Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ 
>   then  $F$ is uniformly continuous in some punctured neighbourhood of $a$.

Let $f$ be differentiable at $a$ and let the derivative of $f$ at $a$ be $f^{'}(a)$.

Then given $\epsilon>0\exists \delta_0 >0$ such that $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{'}(a)|<\epsilon $ whnever $0<|x-a|<\delta_0$.

I take the punctured neighbourhood to be $B(a,\delta_0)$.

Now if we choose $x,y\in B(a,\delta_0)$ then $|\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{'}(a)|<\epsilon $ and $|\dfrac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-f^{'}(a)|<\epsilon $

Now to show that $F$ is uniformly continuous in $B(a,\delta_0)$,take $\epsilon>0$ and we choose $\delta=\delta_0/2$

then $|F(x)-F(y)|=|(\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{'}(a))-(|\dfrac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-f^{'}(a)|)|<|\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}-f^{'}(a)|+|\dfrac{f(y)-f(a)}{y-a}-f^{'}(a)|<2\epsilon$

whenever $0<|x-a|<\delta_0$.

Hence $F$ is uniformly continuous.

But my friend said he has found a counter-example where he has taken $f(x)=x^21_{\Bbb Q}$.

Where is the fault in my argument?Please help me to find out why my proof is not correct?

Comment: I did not say globally differentiable in my question at all@NDewolf

Comment: My apologies, i had misread your question and thought $f$ also had to be differentiable in a punctured neighbourhood.

Comment: This is false, unless $f$ is assumed continuous. (Umm, just noticed that this is what your friend has pointed out, in effect …)

Comment: Yes but where lies the problem in my proof@HaraldHanche-Olsen;I know that this is false

Comment: As you can see, I added an answer. (It is also possible that you responded to my comment before I edited it, adding the parentheses.) But anyhow, a meta-comment: The lack of a space before the @ sign meant that I didn't get a notification of your comment. Either put the @… bit at the start of the comment, or remember to put a space before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only flaw in your argument is at the very end: You need the inequality whenever $0<|x-y|<\delta$, and your argument does not give you that. But actually, you started going wrong a bit earlier, when you said to choose $x,y\in B(a,\delta_0)$. But that will constrain you to a neighbourhood of $a$, smaller and smaller as $\epsilon$ shrinks, and that spells disaster for your proof idea.

**Edited to add:** You have proved, quite correctly, that given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $|F(x)-F(y)|<2\epsilon$ whenever $|x-a|<\delta$ **and** $|y-a|<\delta$ (you left out the last part).

But that is not the definition of uniform continuity, so you haven't shown that. For uniform continuity, you need to show that given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $|F(x)-F(y)|<2\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$. But since $|x-y|<\delta$ does not imply either one of $|x-a|<\delta$ or $|y-a|<\delta$, much less both at the same time, your proof does not work.

**Edit the second,** in response to the edit of the question on June 9:

Note that you are supposed to show that $F$ is uniformly continuous in somme punctured neighbourhood of $a$. That means: *There exists* such a punctured neigbourhood, say $U$, so that, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ so that $x,y\in U$ and $|x-y|<\delta$ imply $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$.

Note the order: The neighbourhood is chosen *first*. You have chosen a neighbourhood depending on $\delta$, and hence on $\epsilon$. But that is an error of logic. Choosing a smaller $\epsilon$ may, in principle, force you to pick a smaller $\delta$, thus changing your neighbourhood.

For reference, here is a correct proof. As you can see, a somewhat bigger gun is needed.

First, note that the differentiability at $a$ implies $\lim_{x\to a}F(x)=f'(a)$. This means that if we *extend the definition* of $F$ by setting $F(a)=f'(a)$, then $F$ is continuous at $a$. By the (omitted) assumption that $f$ is continuous, it now follows that $F$ is continuous everywhere.

Next, recall that a continuous function on a closed and bounded interval is uniformly continuous. So $F$ is uniformly continuous on $[a-1,a+1]$, say. But then it is also uniformly continuous on any subset of that interval, in particular, on the punctured neighbourhood $(a-1,a+1)\setminus\{a\}$.

Comment: I am not getting it .Is it possible to tell me the line where the logic is faulty

Comment: The exact line where your logic is faulty, is the one where you write “Hence $F$ is uniformly continuous.” There is also a smaller logic failure just before it, but that is the big one. I'll see if I can expand my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you again,will you kindly say where lies the exact fault in the argument,I have added more steps to make it easier for you

Comment: Corresponding to your last line "does not imply that.. .. one of $|x-a|<\delta$" please check my logic given in my next comment

Comment: $|x-a|<\delta,|y-a|<\delta$ is always true I guess since $x,y\in B(a,\delta)\setminus \{a\}$

Comment: I edited the answer in response to your edit of the question. I hope this one settles it; we can't keep doing this forever.

Comment: Yes,thank you very much;It has cleared all my doubts